# Obtener el número de teléfono desde Android?

Tags: java, android

Como puedo obtener el numero de teléfono que use mi aplicación?

Quisiera obtenerlo cuando pulsen un botón de mi aplicación. Y este se pueda almacenar para posteriormente usarlo.

Comment: es muy ambigua tu pregunta, describe más tu problema, por favor.

Comment: Creo que lo quiere es obtenere progamaticalmente el numero de telefono del movil que utilice la app al pulsar un botón @eyllanesc

Comment: Cierto, Quiero obtener el número, para poderlo almacenarlo y posteriormente llamar al usuario. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con este código:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

En el `adroid Manifest`, debes añadir este permiso:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Con esto obtienes el numero de teléfono, te quedaria añadir el evento `onclick` del botón